# Centering Bootstrap input field based on full screen width size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Full screen input box]

[image: Browser window resized]

```
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Full Width Layout</h1>
    <p class="lead">The Bootstrap 3 grid is fluid only. This example shows how to use a custom container to create a fixed width layout.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="http://bootply.com/tagged/bootstrap-3" target="ext">More Examples</a></p>
```

@example.com

1) I am trying to centre the input box, with the submit button next to it.
2) When I resize the browser window the input box shrinks, how can I prevent this from happening. Thanks

Comment: try setting a `min-width` css parameter for the input box

Comment: Thanks that works, is there a better way to centre the input box rather than wrapping the div around <center> </center>

Comment: Try like this: <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7" style="min-width: 270px;">
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="test" style="margin: auto; width:50%;">
</div>

Comment: pls check if this is what you are looking for http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: Thanks margin:auto did the trick